# The name 'UIFramework' does not exist in the current context

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

I created a new asp.net core web application which uses individual user accounts. And I want to allow users to sing-in using their Microsoft accounts. so i tried following this tutorial https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/social/microsoft-logins?view=aspnetcore-2.2..
but when i tried adding this inside our startup.cs :-

```
 services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>()
        .AddDefaultUI(UIFramework.Bootstrap4)
        .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();

            services.AddAuthentication().AddMicrosoftAccount(microsoftOptions =>
            {
                microsoftOptions.ClientId = Configuration["Authentication:Microsoft:ApplicationId"];
                microsoftOptions.ClientSecret = Configuration["Authentication:Microsoft:Password"];
            });
```

I got this error:-

> Error CS0103  The name 'UIFramework' does not exist in the current
>   context

so i am not sure how i can add a referecne to `UIFramework`? 
thanks

Comment: Which version of ASP.NET Core are you targetting?

Comment: @Kirk Larkin I am using .NET Core 2.1 inside VS 2017..

Comment: That's your issue - `UIFramework` was added in 2.2.

Comment: @Kirk Larkin so should i upgrade the .NET core? i just installed VS 2017 and i just created the new project,, so i would assume that i should have the latest version of .net core..

Comment: That's up to you - 2.1 is LTS but 2.2 is the latest. You might not have the latest .NET Core SDK installed.

Comment: @KirkLarkin but if i want to fix the issue i am facing then i will need .net core 2.2??

Comment: I think you can just remove `UIFramework.Bootstrap4` from the code you've shown, which will use Bootstrap 3 as that was the only option in 2.1.

Answer (score 7):

**For .NET Core 3 developers**:

(A breaking change)

For bootstrap 4 use: `.AddDefaultUI();`
For bootstrap 3 use: `.AddDefaultUI();` and then override the version by adding

```
<IdentityUIFrameworkVersion>Bootstrap3</IdentityUIFrameworkVersion>
```

inside your project file.
See: https://github.com/aspnet/Announcements/issues/380

Answer (score 1):

UIFramework was added in .NEt Core 2.2
you can upgrade from .NEt Core 2.1 to 2.2 
Or just delete this 
.AddDefaultUI(UIFramework.Bootstrap4)